# How to stop TeamCity from building a pull request when it is viewed or commented?

Tags: github, teamcity

Currently, my team is using TeamCity to automatically build pull requests from GitHub.

We have a configuration to build all the pull requests. In the version control settings of the config, our branch specification is

```
+:refs/pull/*/merge
```

In the "Build Triggers" configuration setting, we have only one trigger with the following trigger rule:

```
+:root=Pull Requests on our Repository:\***/*\*
```

"Pull Requests on our Repository" is our VCS root name.

The issues:

- When someone views a pull request on GitHub website without doing anything else, a build would be triggered in the TeamCity build agent. This is quite annoying, because from time to time, we have multiple build agents building the same pull requests (when multiple people view it).
- When someone comments on a pull request, a build would also be triggered.

From my perspective, the only time I want TeamCity to start a build is when new commits are pushed to the pull requests.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Can this be done with Gitlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have TeamCity configured as per this [blog post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/02/automatically-building-pull-requests-from-github-with-teamcity/)? I then activate the [TeamCity service hook](http://www.jaxzin.com/2011/02/teamcity-build-triggering-by-github.html) in GitHub which takes care of triggering a build in TeamCity whenever there is a push. This seems to do the right thing for me. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

Github's `refs/pull/*/merge` branches are updated every time mergeability of the branch is recalculated, i.e. on every commit to destination (most likely `master`) branch. They are also updated when pull request is closed and then reopened. Github's support says these branches are not intended for end users use. The only workaround at the moment is to run builds on `refs/pull/*/head` branches automatically and on `refs/pull/*/merge` branches manually.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I wanted to post what we've found as alternatives:

- Stop using VCS roots altogether as a mechanism for triggering pull requests. Instead, configure a [GitHub webhook](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestevent) to notify a web app of yours whenever there is an update to a PR and only then [trigger a build via the TeamCity REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-TriggeringaBuild).
- In your build config, add a step that checks what changed in the PR. If nothing changed (i.e. no new commits were added), or if the PR is closed, cancel the build. The problem with this is that the build queue will still be populated with builds that will then be cancelled. Also, you'd have to store somewhere the last commit that was built in order to do the check.

Answer (score 0):

According to their [TeamCity's issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-33455), the issue of the TeamCity.GitHub plugin causing an infinite loop of builds was fixed in v9.0